# AngularJS using custom directive containing input in form - validation issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have problems with AngularJS using custom directive containing input in form.

The html of the directive is as:

```
    <div class="form-group" data-width="{{vm.width}}" ng-class=" { 'has-error': {{vm.formName}}.{{vm.elementName}}.$invalid } ">

<label class="control-label" for="{{vm.elementName}}">
    {{vm.labelText}} <i ng-show="vm.isRequired" class="fa fa-asterisk form-control-required-symbol"></i>
</label>
<input class="form-control" data-width="{{vm.width}}" id="{{vm.elementName}}" name="{{vm.elementName}}" ng-required="{{vm.isRequired}}" type="text" ng-model="vm.value" placeholder="{{vm.placeholderText}}" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="{{vm.elementName}}" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

I have a plunk - please check it out and help me on this one :-)
http://plnkr.co/edit/jFqMXVCKCSUpwij6aTUB?p=preview

Best regards.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is validation. The ng-class="{ 'has-error': ...  does not work :-(